# Why is ContentPlaceHolder content not displaying under IE9?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9, contentplaceholder

I'm working on a small ASP.NET project and just hit a wall.  In a middle of a project, I started to test the webpage on different browsers and detected that the content of the `ContentPlaceHolder` in `MasterPage` is not showing under IE9.

When I hit the compatibility view button, then it did displayed, but this is not a solution to my problem.

I do not have this problem in other browsers.

You can check it yourself at: http://webservice2.gls-hungary.com/NotificationService/

Comment: It's a css problem, not an asp.net problem. I've tried a few css things and it has something to do with this one <div style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; padding-bottom: 20px; background-color: white; padding-left: 20px; width: 760px; bottom: 10px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; left: 2px;"> for instance delete the width and see the result... My advise is to use relative position and float:left; to position your form. I'm not to confident with absolute positioning to present you a solution to this problem

Comment: You got the point! Please copy your comment as solution and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a css problem, not an asp.net problem. I've tried a few css things and it has something to do with this one

`<div style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; padding-bottom: 20px; background-color: white; padding-left: 20px; width: 760px; bottom: 10px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; left: 2px;">`

for instance delete the width and see the result... My advise is to use relative position and float:left; to position your form. I'm not to confident with absolute positioning to present you a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
 #containerDiv{clear:both;float:left;display:block;}
```